# Perform transaction-like operations on List<T>

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do transactions with the List?

With commits and rollbacks, so i can .Add(a); .Add(b);
and then perform a rollback to reset to the previous state.

Is this possible? Or is there an other eay to do this without using an external database and loosing performance that way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273). Why do you need transactions on list methods like `Add()`? What are you actually trying to do? That sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the Command pattern, which allows you to do multiple undo.

Comment: This is an unusual requirement. Perhaps you could explain the use case to make your question more understandable (and getting rid of the down- and close-votes).

Comment: Or possibly an `ImmutableList`, and keep a hold of the previous list at the start of operations, then to rollback just replace with the old list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List` and `List<T>` classes do not have this functionality built in. What you can do is  set up a lock so that no other threads can access the list while it is being changed. Then you can log all the changes you make in a stack and if there is a failure apply the reverse of all the operations in the stack before finally releasing the lock. Something like this:

```
private static readonly List<object> _list = new List<object>();
private static readonly object _listLock = new object();

private void AddObjects(object[] objArrray)
{
    lock (_listLock)
    {
        var objectsAdded = new Stack<Object>(objArray.Count);
        try
        {
            foreach (object o in objArray)
            {
                objectsAdded.Push(o);
                _list.Add(o);
                // Do something that might throw an exception
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            while (objectsAdded.Count > 0)
            {
                _list.Remove(objectsAdded.Pop());
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is quite crude. It does not handle operations that remove, replace or move objects in the list. To do that you would want to record the operation type along with all the data you need to reverse the operation.

Finally it is worth noting that this is not as robust as a database because it isn't stored on durable media. As such any power cut will wipe the list with no log of changes required to recreate it.

Comment: This answer is a great help, thank you.